# The listener for function 'Functions.trigger' was unable to start? while running Azure function locally

Tags: python, azure, macos, web-scraping, undetected-chromedriver

Error while during local run:

The listener for function 'Functions.trigger' was unable to start. Azure.Core: Retry failed after 6 tries. Retry settings can be adjusted in ClientOptions.Retry. (nodename nor servname provided, or not known (--------.blob.core.windows.net:443)) (nodename nor servname provided, or not known (--------.blob.core.windows.net:443)) (nodename nor servname provided, or not known (--------.blob.core.windows.net:443)) (nodename nor servname provided, or not known (--------.blob.core.windows.net:443)) (nodename nor servname provided, or not known (--------.blob.core.windows.net:443)) (nodename nor servname provided, or not known (--------.blob.core.windows.net:443)). Azure.Core: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (--------.blob.core.windows.net:443). System.Net.Http: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (--------.blob.core.windows.net:443). System.Net.Sockets: nodename nor servname provided, or not known.
I have masked the "Account name",information

During the debug:

Exception has occurred: TypeError
issubclass() arg 1 must be a class
File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-functions-core-tools@4/4.0.3971/workers/python/3.9/OSX/X64/azure/functions/_thirdparty/werkzeug/exceptions.py", line 695, in _find_exceptions
is_http_exception = issubclass(obj, HTTPException)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-functions-core-tools@4/4.0.3971/workers/python/3.9/OSX/X64/azure/functions/_thirdparty/werkzeug/exceptions.py", line 707, in
_find_exceptions()
File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-functions-core-tools@4/4.0.3971/workers/python/3.9/OSX/X64/azure/functions/_thirdparty/werkzeug/datastructures.py", line 2836, in
from . import exceptions
File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-functions-core-tools@4/4.0.3971/workers/python/3.9/OSX/X64/azure/functions/_http.py", line 12, in
from ._thirdparty.werkzeug import datastructures as _wk_datastructures
File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-functions-core-tools@4/4.0.3971/workers/python/3.9/OSX/X64/azure/functions/init.py", line 8, in
from ._http import HttpRequest
File "/Volumes/Project/ETFAnalyser/AzureProject/trigger/init.py", line 6, in
import azure.functions as func
File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-functions-core-tools@4/4.0.3971/workers/python/3.9/OSX/X64/azure_functions_worker/loader.py", line 85, in load_function
mod = importlib.import_module(fullmodname)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-functions-core-tools@4/4.0.3971/workers/python/3.9/OSX/X64/azure_functions_worker/utils/wrappers.py", line 40, in call
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-functions-core-tools@4/4.0.3971/workers/python/3.9/OSX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 305, in _handle__function_load_request
func = loader.load_function(
File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-functions-core-tools@4/4.0.3971/workers/python/3.9/OSX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 257, in _dispatch_grpc_request
resp = await request_handler(request)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-functions-core-tools@4/4.0.3971/workers/python/3.9/OSX/X64/azure_functions_worker/main.py", line 50, in main
return aio_compat.run(start_async(
File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-functions-core-tools@4/4.0.3971/workers/python/3.9/OSX/X64/worker.py", line 86, in
main.main()

local.settings.host

````
"IsEncrypted": false,
"Values": {
"AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=--------;AccountKey=-------------;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python"
}
}```


How to resolve the issue ?
````

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the issue in my local environment, by following the below steps:

- Created a python function with Timer trigger as function using visual studio code.
- Using local storage  we are able to run the function
  successfully.
- We have replaced  the  "AzureWebJobsStorage" value with
  connection string of azure storage account & came across multiple
  issue while running the function like .

[image]

[image]

I can fix those errors by using below steps:

Make sure you run your  **Storage Emulator**  with  **Admin**  privileges.

Killing the  **Function process**  &  **host process**  in the task manager

[image]

Posting killing the above function & host process when have re-ran the function Now I can able to run the azure function without issue:

[image]

Comment: thanks @venkatesh for the update.As per the site [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json)storage emulator support only Windows.Since i am on MacOs this solution won't work.Currently exploring the how to connect local storage using Azurite

Comment: @Amith , you can refer this [github link](https://github.com/Azure/Azurite) about Azurite